# Just like ntile in window function divides the rows in equal parts by assigning nos. Is there a way to do that in unequal parts in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a column with a string value "xyz" and it's count is 100. I want to split this column into 3 parts in the ratio 30% 50% and 20%. Just like ntile does but it splits equally. I want to do unequal split

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Do you have a row_number() function in your RDBMS?  you could simply use a case when rowno <30 then 1 when between 31 and 80 then 2, etc.